# Two definitions of a degree of map $f: S^n \to S^n$ equivalent?

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, de-rham-cohomology

Given a smooth map $f: S^n \to S^n$, I have seen at least two ways of defining the degree.

Definition 1: $\deg f$ is an integer satisfying, for every $\omega \in \Omega^n(S^n)$,
$$\int_{S^n} f^*\omega = (\deg f) \int_{S^n} \omega.$$
This definition comes from the theory of de Rham cohomology.

Definition 2: Since $\pi_n(S^n)\simeq \mathbb Z$, the induced map $f_*: \pi_n(S^n) \to \pi_n(S^n)$ is a multiplication by constant, which is defined as $\deg f$.

Does the two definitions equivalent?

Comment: Yes they are equivalent, as $H^n(\Bbb S^n,\Bbb Z)\cong \pi_n(\Bbb S^n)$ "naturally".

Comment: @User Thanks for your answer. I am not familiar with the "advanced" aspects of algebraic topology, so could you elaborate your answer, e.g. by giving the name of the relevant theorems or references?

Comment: Interestingly, I've never seen your second definition. I've always seen it with the induced map $H_n(X,\Bbb Z)\to H_n(X,\Bbb Z)$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a Hurewicz homomorphism $\Phi:\pi_n(S^n) \to H_n(S^n)$ given by taking a class of a map $\pi_n(S^n)\ni[\alpha]:S^n \to S^n$ and sending it to $\alpha_*([S^n])$ where $[S^n]$ is the fundamental class, or the generator for $H_n(S^n)$. It is an isomorphism here.

This map is natural in the sense that for any map $f:S^n \to S^n$ and $[\alpha] \in \pi_n(X)$ we have that $\Phi(f_!([\alpha])=f_!(\Phi([\alpha]))$.

The point here is that $\Phi$ preserves degree! This buys you that definition two is equivalent to the induced homomorphism $f_*:H_n(S^n) \to H_n(S^n)$

To make this leap to the first definition, you will  need to make the use of  the [De-Rham isomorphism](https://scholar.harvard.edu/files/pspark/files/derham.pdf).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I read an wiki article on Hurewicz homomorphism, and it is so remarkable!

Comment: @eigenvalue yeah it’s pretty nuts!